# How to enable instances for Apache ActiveMQ running on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, activemq-classic

I've just installed ActiveMQ using `apt-get` on Ubuntu 11.10.

Every time I try to start it I can see on in the console:

```
No instances found at /etc/activemq/instances-enabled.
```

To start the service I'm using `service` command as follow:

```
$ sudo service activemq start
```

It looks to me like approach to configuring Apache2 on Ubuntu, but I've failed to find any documentation on how to manage instances. Perhaps anyone here could give me a hand?

Comment: Do you know how to get to the Web console? [Here's one suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6956587/156060), but it didn't work for me. Looks like a start, but the paths in jetty.xml don't match up.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.jmkg.co.uk/2010/08/31/installing-activemq-on-ubuntu/) worked much better for me than the deb package that `apt-get` installs.

Comment: just in case, the same behavior happens on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 39):

The install has a default configuration in /etc/activemq/instances-available/main

So typing this in the console should work.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/activemq/instances-available/main /etc/activemq/instances-enabled/main
```

Comment: Bummer there's no equivalent for the apache2 package's `a2enmod`, `a2ensite`, etc.

Comment: Note that after you create the symbolic link, you must run `sudo service activemq restart`, not `sudo service activemq start` because you must stop then start the service.  I think this may be due to a bug in the service initialization script.

Comment: The activemq package should also enable this default configuration.  I think this is a bug in the package.

Answer (score 6):

If you install activemq package on Ubuntu 12.04 (not sure about 11.10) some other helpful documentation available here:

```
/usr/share/doc/activemq/README.Debian
```

Sample configs (for example with web console and stomp API) here:

```
/usr/share/doc/activemq/examples/
```