# Setting Up ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, ubuntu-12.04

I have followed a tutorial to install ActiveMQ http://servicebus.blogspot.com/2011/02/installing-apache-active-mq-on-ubuntu.html

I dont quite understand this part of the tutorial

```
Now, you must create the data/jmx.password and data/jmx.access files
```

How should I work this out?

I tried running the service by

```
sudo /etc/init.d/activemq start
```

and I get this response

```
INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties 
to get details
INFO: changing to user 'activemq' to invoke java
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
INFO: pidfile created : '/opt/activemq/data/activemq-iandjx-GA-MA785GMT-USB3.pid' (pid 
'6092')
```

but I'm still unable to connect to

```
http://localhost:8161
```

Thanks in advance.

I also tried `sudo apt-get install activemq` then

```
activemq
```

which gave me

```
INFO: Loading '/usr/share/activemq/activemq-options'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk//bin/java'
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
/usr/bin/activemq: 399: /usr/bin/activemq: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk//bin/java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true                -Dactivemq.classpath="/var/lib/activemq/conf;"               -Dactivemq.home="/usr/share/activemq"               -Dactivemq.base="/var/lib/activemq/"               -Dactivemq.conf="/var/lib/activemq/conf"               -Dactivemq.data="/var/lib/activemq/data"                              -jar "/usr/share/activemq/bin/run.jar" : not found
Tasks provided by the sysv init script:
    restart         - stop running instance (if there is one), start new instance
    console         - start broker in foreground, useful for debugging purposes
    status          - check if activemq process is running
    setup           - create the specified configuration file for this init script
                      (see next usage section)

Configuration of this script:
    The configuration of this script can be placed on /etc/default/activemq or /home/iandjx/.activemqrc.
    To use additional configurations for running multiple instances on the same operating system
    rename or symlink script to a name matching to activemq-instance-<INSTANCENAME>.
    This changes the configuration location to /etc/default/activemq-instance-<INSTANCENAME> and
    $HOME/.activemqrc-instance-<INSTANCENAME>. Configuration files in /etc have higher precedence.
```

Comment: having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check /etc/default/activemq for this line and note the username and password:

```
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_CONTROL="--jmxurl service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/j
mxrmi --jmxuser USERNAME --jmxpassword PASSWORD"
```

Your jmx.password file should contain the username/password pair

```
USERNAME PASSWORD
```

Your jmx.access file should contain the username followed by readwrite

```
USERNAME readwrite
```

Answer (score 2):

to start the server in interactive mode, go to /bin and run `./activemq console`

Answer (score 1):

> activemq start

should work for starting it.

> activemq status

should tell if the service is running or not.

It may be possible that you have to run once to create the PID file, and then re-run to make it work, as describer in this answer: [Activemq will not start on my Ubuntu VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231640/activemq-will-not-start-on-my-ubuntu-vm)

In case it is running and you just can't connect to the web console, check this other Q/A: [ActiveMQ console not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947224/activemq-console-not-available/6956587#6956587)

Answer (score 0):

**sudo** is necessary.

```
bin$ sudo ./activemq start
bin$ sudo ./activemq status
INFO: Loading '/opt/runtime/apache-activemq-5.11.1/bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
ActiveMQ is running (pid '29887')
```

Answer (score 0):

open file  vim /etc/default/activemq and comment line #ACTIVEMQ_USER="activemq"

now go to bin folder in apache-activemq and run it by using command ./activemq start