# ActiveMQ Admin web console error

Tags: java, apache, jms, message-queue, mom

I'm using apache ActiveMQ 6.0 on windows 7. I ran the `run.bat` in the `bin` folder and tested the web console on http://localhost:8161/ and it is working fine.

But when I try to go to the admin mode through http://localhost:8161/admin, an error occurs :

```
HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /admin. 
Reason: Not Found.
```

What is the solution?

Comment: See if this helps :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947224/activemq-console-not-available

Comment: @ring-bearer ActiveMQ 6.0 is the only version where the web console actually works , and in the config folder there is no jetty.xml like other versions. The problem with other versions is that the prompt appears than closes abruptly everytime I try to run the bat file and i have already checked the questions about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bin directory of extracted ActiveMQ from command prompt.
Run the activemq command as "activemq start".
Then check for http://localhost:8161/admin