# Install ActiveMQ on CentOS cannot open admin and other webpages

Tags: java, linux, apache, centos, activemq-classic

I am installing ActiveMQ 5.13.1 on CentOS 6.7. I am fellowing this tutorial: https://rburnham.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/installing-and-managing-activemq-on-centos/.

I almost fellow the steps, now I can access 
http://xxx.xxx.xx:8161/ from remote client, it shows "Welcome to the Apache ActiveMQ!" page, but once I open http://xxx.xxx.xx:8161/admin, error appears:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /admin/. Reason:

Server Error

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/web/filter/ApplicationContextFilter$2
at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.createRequestContextWrapper(ApplicationContextFilter.java:168)
at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.apache.activemq.web.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Powered by Jetty://
```

Actually some steps I cannot achieve:

```
sudo /opt/activemq/bin/activemq-admin list
```

It said there is no activemq-admin.

After I do :

```
sudo /opt/activemq/bin/activemq setup /etc/default/activemq
```

/etc/default/activemq is not created. so I cannot do:

```
sudo chown root /etc/default/activemq
```

and

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/default/activemq
```

I also fellow another answer( [ActiveMQ console not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947224/activemq-console-not-available) ) change the config file from

```
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
```

to

```
<import resource="${activemq.base}/conf/jetty.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem after installing maven , for workaround did uninstall maven and perform the below steps.

Tried to reinstall activemq .

brew reinstall activemq.

after this restart the system as well.